# Getting Name Error name 'sentence_stream' is not defined

Tags: python, nltk, nameerror

I would like to use trigrams and bigrams because I do not want to use just unigrams.

```
bigramer = gensim.models.Phrases(sentences)
model = Word2Vec(bigramer[sentences], workers=num_workers, \
            size=num_features, min_count = min_word_count, \
            window = context, sample = downsampling)
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk import trigrams
from gensim.models import Phrases
from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser
trigrams = Phrases(bigrams[sentence_stream])
```

However, I am having this error.

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-15b0101c13b1> in <module>()
----> 1 trigrams = Phrases(bigrams[sentence_stream])

NameError: name 'sentence_stream' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is `sentence_stream` defined? Looks like it's missing...

Comment: your code snippet doesn't have `sentence_stream` variable anywhere prior to you using it in the last line of your snippet

Comment: I am aware that it is not defined because I am trying to learn how to write your own word embedding according to this example;
https://taylorwhitten.github.io/blog/word2vec
It is not defined in this example too. For that reason I thought maybe it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by rewriting the code as :

```
bigram = Phrases(sentences, min_count=1, threshold=1)
print list(bigram[sentences])

trigram = Phrases(bigram[sentences],min_count=1, threshold=1)
print list(trigram[bigram[sentences]])
```